# Qt c++ диалоговое окно относительно размера tableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Привет всем. Есть QDialog ui форма сделанная в дизайнере. В окне есть tableWidget, как сделать так чтобы окно менялось в зависимости от того какая ширина колонок в tableWidget. У меня tableWidget 6 колонок на 10 строк с возможностью их расширения. Если слово не помещается, автоматически расширяется колонка. Но так как минимальный размер фиксирован появляется скролл вправо, а хотелось бы просто расширить окно по тому где заканчивается последняя колонка.

Comment: Есть в WINAPI ф-ция которая меряет ширину шрифта в пикселях `GetTextExtentPoint` шрифт нужно вложить в *dc*. Вычислив размер - вы можете вручную разширить диалог. К сожелению у винды я не видел ф-ций авторазширения. Может в qt-пакете что-то и есть.

Answer (score 2):

Примерный код такой

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QRect r = geometry();
    int dw=72;
    r.setWidth(ui->tableWidget->sizeHint().width()+dw);
    setGeometry(r);    
}
```

dw - отступы для таблицы. Считать в зависимости от формы